# Heroku GeoDjango issues with missing GDAL (and possibly GEOS)

Tags: python, django, heroku, gdal, geodjango

I'm working on a GeoDjango application and am using Heroku (with a Heroku-16 stack) as my platform.

I am following the instructions found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-c-deps#geodjango-application-libraries), which specify the following:

> If your application requires geo libraries, experimental support for a handful of these libraries are available:
>
> - GDAL v2.2.1 (v1.11.5 for cedar-14)
> - Geos v3.6.2 (v3.4.2 for cedar-14)
> - Proj v4.9.3 (v4.8.0 for cedar-14)
>
> To make these libraries available to your application, simply set the BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES environment variable:

```
$ heroku config:set BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES=1
```

> During your next build, these libraries will be downloaded and installed.
>   In your Django settings.py, also add the following:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 
'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'

GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

> This will ensure that Django can find the GEOS libraries that are installed.

I have set the env variables in Heroku:

[image]

However, I have found that this isn't making a difference when it's time to deploy:

```
2017-09-23T19:29:55.142378+00:00 app[web.1]:     % '", "'.join(lib_names)
2017-09-23T19:29:55.142414+00:00 app[web.1]: 
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL 
library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0", "gdal1.11.0", 
"gdal1.10.0", "gdal1.9.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting 
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

Here's my requirements.txt:

```
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.11.5
gunicorn==19.6.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
pytz==2017.2
whitenoise==3.2
```

The only anomaly I have here is that I'm using Django 1.11.5 instead of what the default was with Heroku's Django project template, which is 1.11.1. This was to fix a problem that kept the project from working that was patched.

Procfile is:

```
web: gunicorn tagging_tracker_backend.wsgi
```

runtime.txt is:

```
python-3.6.2
```

The Github repo is at [this](https://github.com/Nerdenator/tagging-tracker-backend) link.

Comment: Try this buildpack, it works as expected https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/cheesecakelabs/heroku-geo-buildpack

Answer (score 6):

Heroku documentation says that:

Note: This feature(BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES) is only known to work well on cedar-14. We are working to ensure that it works properly on heroku-16, slowly.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-c-deps#geodjango-application-libraries

In order to use cedar-14:

```
$ heroku stack:set cedar-14 --app YOUR_APP
```

Comment: NOTE for others: cedar-14 is now REALLY out of date. Current default is Heroku-20.

Answer (score 4):

1) Change your Django settings.py:

Before:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

Now:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.environ.get('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.environ.get('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

2) Set config var:

```
$ heroku config:set BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES=1
```

3) Change Heroku's stack:

```
$ heroku stack:set cedar-14
```

Answer (score 1):

[Heroku now has a buildpack for geo libraries](https://help.heroku.com/D5INLB1A/python-s-build_with_geo_libraries-legacy-feature-is-no-longer-supported).

They suggest:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack.git
```

Answer (score 0):

For latest version we can use

`heroku stack:set cedar-18 --app YOUR_APP`

Comment: According to heroku doc: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack cedar-18 is not available