# Internal Server Error:/admin/login/ DoesNotExist at /admin/login Site matching query does not exist`

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

After completing Coreys blogging YouTube series and Mitchels ecommerce Udemy course, I have tried to merge the two together and adding mapping functionality. Adding the mapping forced me to change the database I was using in production mode. Which may have triggered the problems.

Below are my setting files. I have them split into base.py (used for development and production), production (used for just production) and development (used for just development).

I have tried

- changing `SITE_ID` to 1,2 and 3.
- enabling and disabling `django.contrib.sites`.
- site = Site.objects.create(domain="rossecommerce.com", name="RossEcommerce")
- site = Site.objects.create(domain="example.com", name="Example")

Example.com has ID 1 and rossecommerce.com has ID 3.

```
   from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
    site = Site.objects.filter()
    print(site)
    <QuerySet [<Site: example.com>, <Site: rossecommerce.com>]>
```

**Note - secret keys and email addresses have been modified, to prevent confidential info being leaked**

****init**.py**

```
from .base import *
# from .local2 import *
from .production import *
```

**base.py**

```
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))



SECRET_KEY = "6a28569690e44af0de19f3eb6b3cb36cb448b7d31f881cde"
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',



    # third party
    'storages',
    'crispy_forms',
    'mptt',
   


    #our apps

   
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'accounts',
    'addresses',
    'analytics',
    'billing',
    'carts',
    'categorytree',
    'discounts',
    'marketing',
    'orders',
    'products',
    'search',
    'tags',
    'properties',
    'floppyforms',
    'photologue',
    'sortedm2m',
    'photologue_custom',
    'taggit',
]


SITE_ID = 2
#SITE_ID = 'http://localhost:8000/'





AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User' #changes the built-in user model to ours


FORCE_SESSION_TO_ONE = False
FORCE_INACTIVE_USER_ENDSESSION= False



MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = "a9782cc1adcd9260907ab76064411efe-us17"
MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = "us17"
MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID = "5a6a2c63a8"

STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = "sk_test_61HDF86ARPAz7urwytx7tO3QCxV4R8AGNXbqj6esg7OKuybiSTI8iJC8mmJUQpg4RKENxuS04DKOCzYHpDkBjUttO00LOmsT4Dg"
STRIPE_PUB_KEY = "pk_test_77HEF86ARPAz8urwyGw9xwLkgbgfCYT11LttupjEkb11I7Ljb1soBtuKXBaPiKfuu0Cx2BzIowR3jJFkD8ybFBAEf00DFY44fB9"


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'EcommerceProject.urls'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # I believe this is related to the dedicated Templates folder which is not part of a specific app
        'DIRS': [os.path.join((BASE_DIR), 'templates')],
       

        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],

            'libraries':{
            'param_replace': 'products.templatetags.param_replace',
            'display_the_sidebar_blog': 'products.templatetags.sidebar_blog',
            'display_sidebar_categorytree': 'products.templatetags.sidebar_categorytree',
            'product_display': 'products.templatetags.product_display',



            }
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'EcommerceProject.wsgi.application'




AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_my_proj"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "static_root")




MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn", "media_root")


CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

GEOIP_PATH =os.path.join('geoip')
```

**production.py**

```
import os
import django_heroku



BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))



ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
SITE_ID = 2

   

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')


EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.live.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'ross545@hotmail.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'ross545@hotmail.com'

SERVER_EMAIL = 'ross545@hotmail.com'
BASE_URL = 'https://www.rossecommerce.com/'

MANAGERS = (
    ('Ross Symonds', "ross545@hotmail.com"),
)

ADMINS = MANAGERS





DEBUG = False




   

FORCE_SESSION_TO_ONE = False
FORCE_INACTIVE_USER_ENDSESSION= False


  
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = os.environ.get('MAILCHIMP_API_KEY')


MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = "us17"
MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID = os.environ.get('MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID')


STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')
STRIPE_PUB_KEY = os.environ.get('STRIPE_PUB_KEY')



 

import dj_database_url
DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)}
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config() #postgreSQL Database in heroku
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 500

'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'

GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')





  
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "static_root")


from EcommerceProject.aws.conf import *

CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER      = True
HOST_SCHEME                     = "https://"
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER         = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT             = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE           = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE              = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS             = 1000000
SECURE_FRAME_DENY               = True





from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING

DEFAULT_LOGGING['handlers']['console']['filters'] = []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After faffing around with the SITE_ID for ages, that turned out to not be the problem at all. When I completed my Udemy Ecommerce project I had these settings -

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config() #postgreSQL Database in heroku
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 500
```

I wanted to add mapping functionality. This required me to change the database I was using. I tried these settings (which I got here [Heroku GeoDjango issues with missing GDAL (and possibly GEOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383875/heroku-geodjango-issues-with-missing-gdal-and-possibly-geos)) -

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 
'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'

GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

Assigning a value to GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH and GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH sorted some issues, but there was still problems with my database.

I then tried the below (some of the details have been slightly modified for confidentially purposes).

```
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
    GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')


django_heroku.settings(locals())

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'd9h09ijdbvh8o9',
        'USER': 'mxsjgmjdxjzdrb',
        'PASSWORD': '95cccb4432b7648956f2c6a9baade9e53ce5c525f74fc098aba38ba0f02ffaf0',
        'HOST': 'ec2-35-174-127-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
}
```

I then got this error message -

```
   django_heroku.settings(locals())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_heroku/core.py", line 99, in settings
    config['MIDDLEWARE'] = tuple(['whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'] + list(config['MIDDLEWARE']))
KeyError: 'MIDDLEWARE'
```

This was my final code -

```
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
    GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')




DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'd9h09ijdbvh8o9',
        'USER': 'mxsjgmjdxjzdrb',
        'PASSWORD': '95cccb4432b7648956f2c6a9baade9e53ce5c525f74fc098aba38ba0f02ffaf0',
        'HOST': 'ec2-35-174-127-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with a default site with PK value **`1`**.

So, setting **`SITE_ID=1`** in your *settings.py* will resolve this error

If you want to *"disable"* the `site` app, remove `django.contrib.sites` from **`INSTALLED_APPS`** section, which is the Django way of disabling an app.

---

#### Update 1

Open the Django shell and run the following statements

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

site = Site.objects.create(
    domain="example.com",
    name="Example"
)
print(site.pk)
```

You will get an integer (the `site.pk` value) and use that particular value in the settings as

**`SITE_ID = XXXX`** where `XXXX` is the `site.pk` value

Comment: I have not disabled the app but have changed SITE_ID to 1. And the error still appears.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I now get the error psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_site_domain_a2e37b91_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (domain)=(example.com) already exists

Comment: try some other value instead of `example`

Comment: I did the following

Comment: >>> site = Site.objects.create(domain="rossecommerce.com", name="RossEcommerce")

Comment: >>> print(site.pk)

Comment: And got the value 3